# expecting EOF, found 'for', Processing

Tags: processing

I'm trying to create a repeating pattern of triangles of varying shapes and sizes with Processing using the following code:

```
int vali = 20;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

color[] mycolors = {#a1a1a1,#575757,#bdbdbd, #747474};

void setup(){
  size (1260,405);
  colorMode(HSB);
  background (0);
}
void mousePressed(){
  background (0);
  noStroke();
  for(int x=0;x<1260;x=x+30)
  for(int y=0;y<405;y=y+350){
    fill(mycolors[int(random(0,4))]);
    triangle(x,y,x,y+vali,x+vali,y+vali);
    fill(mycolors[int(random(0,4))]);
    triangle(x,y,x+vali,y,x+vali,y+vali);
  }
}

for(int x=0;x<1260;x=x+100){
  for(int y=0;y<405;y=y+220){
    fill(mycolors[int(random(0,4))]);
    triangle(x+12,y+270,x+27,y+320,x+600,y+230);
    fill(mycolors[int(random(0,4))]);
    triangle(x+260,y+390,x+720,y+130,x+900,y+600);
  }
}
void draw(){
}
```

But for some reason it gives me this error:"expecting EOF, found 'for'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nested for loop is out of the body of the function `mousePressed`. This causes an syntactical error.
Move the code "inside" the function to solve your issue:

```
void mousePressed(){
    background (0);
    noStroke();
    for(int x=0;x<1260;x=x+30)
    for(int y=0;y<405;y=y+350){
        fill(mycolors[int(random(0,4))]);
        triangle(x,y,x,y+vali,x+vali,y+vali);
        fill(mycolors[int(random(0,4))]);
        triangle(x,y,x+vali,y,x+vali,y+vali);
    }

// } <--- remove

    for(int x=0;x<1260;x=x+100){
        for(int y=0;y<405;y=y+220){
            fill(mycolors[int(random(0,4))]);
            triangle(x+12,y+270,x+27,y+320,x+600,y+230);
            fill(mycolors[int(random(0,4))]);
            triangle(x+260,y+390,x+720,y+130,x+900,y+600);
        }
    }

} //  <--- add
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind explaining why does this work without having anything inside the draw function? https://github.com/joopajoo/Processing-test/blob/master/.gitignore/.gitignore

Comment: @AapoPitkänen Because the code is not inside the `draw` function, but it is inside the `mousePressed` function. The for loop  can be inside any function, but the for statement outside the function is syntactically incorrect.